# 'snap refresh' reports pkgs are updated while newer pkgs are available in upstream

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

## Question

I think I should be able to install a newer version. What am I missing?

## Issue

[Release-notes of a package `home-assistant-snap`](https://www.home-assistant.io/blog/categories/release-notes/) shows the latest ver is `2022.5` and yet on my `Ubuntu Core` on RPi3 the latest is `2021.12.3`. 5 months lagging. [Its snap page (snapcraft.io)](https://snapcraft.io/home-assistant-snap) also lists that the `latest/stable` is `2022.5`.

```
$ snap refresh home-assistant-snap --channel=latest/edge
home-assistant-snap (edge) 2021.12.3 from Giaever.online (giaever-online) refreshed
```

## Environment

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 5.4.0-1060-raspi #68~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 26 15:06:03 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

$ snap list
Name                 Version                Rev    Tracking       Publisher       Notes
classic              18.04-0.1              48     18/edge        canonical?      devmode
core                 16-2.54.4              12838  latest/stable  canonical?      core
core18               20220428               2407   latest/stable  canonical?      base
core20               20220329               1436   latest/stable  canonical?      base
home-assistant-snap  2021.12.3              459    latest/edge    giaever-online  -
pi                   18-1                   117    18-pi/stable   canonical?      gadget
pi-kernel            5.4.0-1060.68~18.04.1  455    18-pi/stable   canonical?      kernel
snapd                2.55.3                 15540  latest/stable  canonical?      snapd
zwavejs2mqtt         v6.8.0                 367    latest/stable  giaever-online  -
```

```
$ snap list --all|grep -i home-assistant
home-assistant-snap  2021.12.3              459    latest/edge    giaever-online  -
home-assistant-snap  2021.12.0              449    latest/edge    giaever-online  disabled
home-assistant-snap  2021.11.5              446    latest/edge    giaever-online  disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building HA for `armhf` was a very tedious task, and since there's now `arm64` versions for the Pi we've stopped maintaining the armhf version.

By swapping to the 64-bit OS you'll get access to the newer releases.

Comment: Thanks for the context! For my particular question though, I guess I'm asking why the tool `snap` doesn't pull the version of a package that was listed at snapcraft.io.

Comment: As I said, there's no version of the architecture available. We've stopped maintaining and releasing HA for the armhf architecture.